# How to give serial number in RecyclerView using adapter class in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i want to add serial number for dynamic response in recycler view from server. what i do please suggest me..

```
    Context context;
    List<Ordere> orderes;

    public MyRewardsAdapter(Context context, List<Ordere> orderes) {
        this.context = context;
        this.orderes = orderes;
    }

    @Override
    public MyRewardsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.reward_list_items,null);
        MyRewardsViewHolder myRewardsViewHolder = new MyRewardsViewHolder(context, view);
        return myRewardsViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyRewardsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtRewardid.setText(orderes.get(position).getOrderid());
        holder.txtrewardpoint.setText(orderes.get(position).getTotal_point());
        holder.txtRewardDate.setText(orderes.get(position).getDate());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return orderes.size();
    }
```

Comment: In onBind you have an attribute called position

Comment: yes, i have but how to add in textView ~santanu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show serial number starting from 0 you can directly use `viewholder.getAdapterPosition()`. If you want to start it from 1 just add it `viewholder.getAdapterPosition()+1` before you set it in any textview.

Comment: yes, it is right but how to set this position value in textView ~ @Karan Mer

Comment: you can simply concatenate it like `tv1.setText(""+viewholder.getAdapterPosition())`

Comment: By mistake I had added the id of the another textview.